# XML Processing in APACHE-Pig scripts

Tags: apache-pig

I have an XML file which has data in a single line ( though with all start and end tags). I tried processing this file through PIG script but the output is still Null. When i convert this to properly indented file i can see the output in output syslog. File is like

```
<HEADER><TAG><VAL1>"value"</VAL1><VAL2>"value2"</VAL2></TAG></HEADER>
```

Is this possible

```
A =  LOAD 'test.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('TAG') as (x:chararray);
DESCRIBE A;

B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,<TAG>\\*s<VAL1>(.*)</VAL1>\\s*<VAL2>(.*)</VAL2></TAG>))
As 
val1:chararray,
val2:chararray)
dump B;
```

Comment: The general answer here is don't use regex to parse xml

Comment: If I use Xpath then i am getting below error

ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Comment: You will have to use Piggybank.jar and register it in your script to use XPath.Download piggybank.jar and register it like this, REGISTER /path/piggybank.jar
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();